# Use text value in cell as Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have text value in a cell and I want to use this value as a formula in the same cell. 
I use find and replace method but no success.

Cell value is

```
=DARTSCRDE|SYMBOL_CHANGEPCOI!'2053049_0'
```

---

```
Sub Replace()
For i = 7 To 48
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G:G").Select
Selection.Replace what:=Cells(i, 7).Value, replacement:=Cells(i, 7).Formula, _
lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False

Next
Worksheets("sheet1").Cells("a1").Select
End Sub
```

Please help me out. I wasted so much time to get a solution.

Comment: How the formula you need should look like if you type it in the cell manually?

Comment: `Range("G7:G47").Formula = Range("G7:G47").Value`

Comment: If the value in the cell is `=DARTSCRDE|SYMBOL_CHANGEPCOI!'2053049_0'` it is the formula, because Excel won't give you to put text with "=" sign without using the ' sign in the beginning.

Comment: if we put manually formula in cell it will give you value N/A.  as its DDE formula.  Manually it will look like

Comment: =  DARTSCRDE|SYMBOL_CHANGEPCOI!'2065139_0'                                            
                                                                                                                            = N/A -------------output

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak I used concatenate  function in this so it is text format including equal to sign.

Comment: `Sub Replace()
For i = 7 To 48
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G:G").Select
Selection.Replace what:=Cells(i, 7).Value, replacement:=Cells(i, 7).Formula, _
lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False

Next
Worksheets("sheet1").Cells("a1").Select
End Sub`

Comment: This code I have recorded and working perfectly but I want dynamic value. Please suggest me how to modidfy like I have mentioned in question code.

Comment: Please move the code from comment to the question, by editing it. Update the point of the question.